# Android AVD System Imge Not Found Android 8 Oreo - But images are installed. (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

So I've run into an issue when trying to create a new virtual device in the android sdk avd. When I select Android 8.0 (Api 26), I am told that a system image cannot be found. This makes no sense to me, as I have in fact installed the image.

However, if I install the Android Wear image, I can select it when creating a new device.

[System Image Installed for 8.0 (With Android Wear image as well)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEGAQ.png)

[Trying to create an 8.0 device, can only select Android Wear image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H6kO.png)

This also happens when trying to create a virtual device for 7.1 Android 7.0 and below have no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried the new (Preview) [Xamarin Android Device Manager](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-emulator/xamarin-device-manager/) ?

Requirements

Visual Studio for Mac 7.4 or later.

The latest version of the Xamarin Device Manager installer for macOS (see note below).

Android SDK – Android SDK 8.0 (API 26) or later must be installed via the SDK Manager.

Comment: Would you believe I found this immidiately after I asked? I spent 3 hours on it! Thanks. This works. [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-emulator/xamarin-device-manager/)